# MYSQL REGEXP in "CASE WHEN"

Tags: mysql, regex, case

I would like to use REGEXP in a CASE WHEN context like this:

```
SELECT
CASE title
  WHEN REGEXP '^(The Matrix|Riddick|American Pie)$' THEN (
    'Movie'
   ) ELSE (
    'FOOO'
   )
END
FROM `movies`
```

but this is not possible. I would like to match different strings here as you can see.

Regards,
Felix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed possible, with the correct syntax.  `REGEXP` requires a left and right side operand, so use the other syntax of `CASE` where the full expression is placed after `WHEN`.

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN `title` REGEXP '^(The Matrix|Riddick|American Pie)$' THEN 'Movie'
    ELSE  'FOOO'
  END AS column_alias
FROM `movies`
```

However, if you are not using any variable elements in the regular expression, this is likely to be far less efficient than doing exact matches on an indexed column.  In other words, you have no need for a regular expression with the example you gave.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN `title` IN ('The Matrix', 'Riddick') THEN 'Movie' 
    ELSE 'FOOO'
  END AS your_column_alias
FROM `movies`
```